# What are the differences between Helper and Utility classes?

Tags: java

How determine how call a class XHelper or XUtils ?

To my mind  :

**Helper class**, is a class that can be instantiate and do some business work

**Utils class**, is a static class that perform small and repetitive operations on a kind of instance (example of utils classes ArrayUtils or IOUtils from Apache)

Comment: "Business work" is the key distinction here. I find it a useful convention to use `Utils` for a static class which could be used anywhere in the organisation, or in another organisation. A `Helper` class has common code which can be re-used within a project and has dependencies within the project. Of course, there is no generally accepted rule, but I find this useful.

Comment: @StephenHosking Your explanation is the most persuading to me & maybe to everyone.  If possible would you post your explanation as actual answer to this post rather than just left comment.

Comment: @Bigair. Thankyou, but mine is only a suggestion, not an answer. I am glad that people have found it helpful.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

There are many naming styles to use. I would suggest Utils just because its more common.

A Utility class is understood to only have static methods and be stateless. You would not create an instance of such a class.

A Helper can be a utility class or it can be stateful or require an instance be created.  I would avoid this if possible.

If you can make the name more specific. e.g. if it has sorting methods, make it XSorter

For arrays you can find helper classes like

```
Array
Arrays
ArrayUtil
ArrayUtils
ArrayHelper
```

BTW a short hand for a utility class is an enum with no instances

```
enum XUtils {;
    static methods here
}
```

If you need to implement an interface, I would use a stateless Singleton.

```
enum XHelper implements RequiredInterface {
   INSTANCE;
   // no instance fields.
}
```

Comment: I this in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/2135797/787698, that Xutils is a static class with no dependencies. What are you thinking about that ?

Comment: @jakcam Interesting point.  A helper could be stateful and require an instance. I would use a stateless and instance-less utility class if possible.

Comment: What are you understand by Xutils is a static class with **no dependencies**?

Comment: I can't find "xutils" or "no dependencies" in that post.

Comment: Won't Utility classes break TDD since you are unable to pass them in as dependencies?

Comment: @John I don't see Dependency Injection as a requirement for TDD. What is the issue?

Comment: If my class or method has dependencies, it's common to use DI to do TDD. You can then use Dummies, Mocks, etc., instead of real implementations of those dependencies. The downside of static classes is that they cannot be easily injected in this manner - they always run live. That creates brittle tests, because they always have to take into account the inner pieces of the class in order to not break the dependencies. Does that make sense?

Comment: @John I guess I am assuming it only make sense to use a utility class if you only intend to have one implementation of that method ever (even in testing) For example, would you use DI to pass in an Array helper class to be able to mock methods like `Arrays.sort(array)` or `Array.getLength(array)` How would doing this make tests less brittle?

Comment: Here's an example: suppose you have a StateAbbreviation helper/util. You probably only want one. Your Foo method takes in a Bar object that includes a state name. Foo converts that state name to a state code and then calls an external Baz service. You want to write a test that tests whether Foo calls Baz. Using DI, you could create a Mock StateAbbreviationUtil + a BazSpy to test that. If you don't use DI, you will need to ensure that Bar.Name can be validly parsed by Bar - something that is unrelated to what you're trying to test. I'm interested in your thoughts.

Comment: @John In that case a utility method isn't desirable as it's harder to mock out for testing purposes.

Comment: At first I just wanted to know if I should name a folder "utils" or "helpers" in a JavaScript projet, I conclude I should use utils as a good practice, as it is more common. This answer, even if it's for Java, works in my case. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterLawrey Could you elaborate on why you won't use a helper method that creates or requires an instance. for example I have helper methods to create and stop my node server, and I just call them from the entry point file to keep my code organized, also I use middlewares and pass around the express router for example, would you suggest anything different?

Comment: A stateful singleton can make the unit tests error prone or make simulating multiple nodes more difficult. If your helper classes are not singletons, then this is a wrapper class IMHO.

Answer (score 40):

In general? It's entirely arbitrary. There are no rules for this.

Answer (score 32):

A utility is a "leaf node" class of general use. That is, it doesn't have any dependencies into your project and can be ported from project to project without breaking or becoming useless. Examples: `Vector3`, `RandomNumberGenerator`, `StringMatcher`, etc...

A "helper" seems to be any class whose design is to aid another class. These may or may not depend on your project.  If you're creating a `GameNetworkClient` class, you could say the `GameNetworkConnection` class is a 'helper', because it "helps" the `GameNetworkClient`.

The way developers refer to tools reflects common usage of these words. If you can recall hearing tools described as "helpful" vs "useful", a helpful tool tends to have some context (cheese grater helps to grate cheese, corn stripper helps to strip corn, speed loader helps to reload a firearm).  A "utility" is expected to work in a variety of contexts (WD-40, duct tape, army-knives, glue, flashlight, etc...).

Answer (score 19):

As Jesper said, it's **entirely arbitrary**. You can think of what works for your organization and make that the convention.

For me, it's something like this:

> **utils** - Static class, that can be freely moved and imported anywhere.

Doing general tasks that could be useful in different modules. As Peter Lawrey said, more *specific names* are useful.

> **helper** - Class *helping* another class or a module.

Tasks that are only used in the module it's placed and won't make sense to be imported elsewhere. Hence the name could be more specific - ***ModuleName*Helper** (e.g. *AdministrationHelper*, *LoginHelper*)

Answer (score 3):

There's no ultimate answer for this. Figure out one naming scheme and stick with it. Naming your packages and classes is an important part of software architecture, and nobody can take that decision away from you.

I personally like the XHelper better, but I see XUtils more often in foreign code.

I also like the "plural" naming scheme you will find both in the JDK and [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

if a class deals with `Collection` objects, it's called `Collections`

Array > Arrays (jdk)
List > Lists (guava)
Map > Maps (guava)

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Helper Functions/Classes: These are functions or classes that are designed to provide support or aid to other parts of the program. They are often used to encapsulate complex or repetitive logic, and are typically defined within a specific module or part of the program. Helper functions/classes may depend on other parts of the program or external libraries, and may be tightly coupled with the code they support. Examples of helper functions/classes might include form validation functions or data formatting classes.

Utility Functions/Classes: These are functions or classes that perform common or generic operations that are not tied to any specific part of the program. They are usually defined separately from the rest of the program and can be used throughout the program or in multiple programs. Utility functions/classes are typically independent of other parts of the program, and may not have any dependencies beyond the standard library. Examples of utility functions/classes might include string manipulation functions or math libraries.

Answer (score 1):

A *Utility* class is one not depending on the usage context (aka, application/system's business or domain) hence is less prone to vary. Examples: StringUtils, MathUtils, etc.

A Utility class does not necessarily have all its methods static, though usually it happens so. Examples:

- a `SortUtils` class that depends on some configuration passed to it at instantiation time to customize how to deal with `null`(s) no matter the business context; e.g. put `null`(s) at the end/start, handle Any*Empty*BusinessObject(s) as `null`, etc
- a `XDomainObjectUtils.toString(xDomainObject)` that based on some customization will return a distinct result, no matter the business context (well, here will matter slightly because it'll have to be something involving a XDomainObject)
- a `LogUtils` class that depends on some configuration passed to it at instantiation time to customize its behaviour

Even if at application/system level more same Utility class instances are needed, each configured differently, as long as Utility class' logic is not dependent on a particular business context, it's still a Utility class.

These might not be the best examples (especially the `LogUtils` one for nowadays) but I guess you see a pattern here: when the utility class has to behave in a configurable fashion then it might no longer have static methods (only) because one needs to parameterize it with the configuration or strategy (see the Strategy pattern) that changes its behaviour.

A *Helper* class is one containing methods dependent on one particular scenario, methods that are not implementing the main logic of that scenario because another class does it. The Helper's methods could stay into the main-logic-implementing-class but doing so would pollute it hence they are better extracted into a distinct class (i.e. Helper). That's why the name: the Helper class is "helping" the main-logic-implementing-class.

Example: `XService` is using `YService` that is throwing `YServiceException`(s) while the `XService`'s methods are supposed to only throw `XServiceException`(s). One could use `try`-`catch` everywhere in `XService` or one could create `XServiceHelper` that's adapting `YServiceService` exceptions to `XServiceException` leaving the XService code more easy to read. This approach makes sense when that `try`-`catch` occurs so many times that really blurs the main code; besides `try`-`catch` once could have verbose types/values conversion/transformation, e.g. `Stream` processing that `reduce` some collection, which again could be moved to a helper if otherwise they bring a significant amount of code in the middle of the main-logic-implementing-class.