# Java Naming Classes: when use Support? But taking in consideration the Helper and Utils too

Tags: java, naming-conventions

About how to name a class how `Helper` or `Utils` it is clearly explained in:

- [What are the differences between Helper and Utility classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192050/what-are-the-differences-between-helper-and-utility-classes)

It such as: `XHelper` or `XUtils`. I did do a research and I got the following results:

About **Utils** we can see for example in `Spring Framework` through:

- [AnnotatedElementUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotatedElementUtils.html)
- [AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/support/AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils.html)
- [AopConfigUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/config/AopConfigUtils.html)

And in `Java` too:

- [BasicGraphicsUtils](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicGraphicsUtils.html)
- [SynthGraphicsUtils](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/synth/SynthGraphicsUtils.html) (it is an **exception** to the rule, because all its methods are *not* `static`)

Same about **Helper** we can see for example in `Spring Framework` through:

- [JsonExpectationsHelper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/JsonExpectationsHelper.html)
- [LocalizedResourceHelper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/LocalizedResourceHelper.html)
- [ReflectionHelper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/spel/support/ReflectionHelper.html) (it is an **exception** to the rule, because all its methods are `static`)

In `Java` is confuse in someway because the are many `Helper` classes where the methods are declared how `static`. Something I had observed is that practically all of them are within the `org.omg` package and not something like `java.xxx` or `javax.yyy`

**Returning to the point**

But what about `Support`? Such as `XSupport`.
It *seems* to be very similar to either `Helper` or `Utils`

There are many classes with this pattern through `Java` such as:

- [BeanContextChildSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/beancontext/BeanContextChildSupport.html)
- [BeanContextServicesSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/beancontext/BeanContextServicesSupport.html)
- [CompositeDataSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/CompositeDataSupport.html)
- [DescriptorSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/modelmbean/DescriptorSupport.html)

and `Spring Framework`

- [ViewResolverSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/view/ViewResolverSupport.html)
- [WebApplicationObjectSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationObjectSupport.html)
- [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html)

So what is the rule(s) to apply definitely the `Support` term for a class name?
(but of course, taking in consideration the two other terms)

Answer (score 2):

**Utils**

Set of static **utility** methods (stateless) of some type e.g. `StringUtils` ([Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/)).

Note there is a more neat convention for such a class: `Strings`, `Iterables`, `Lists` ([Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/index.html)), which is also used in Java (`Arrays`, `Collections`).

**Helper**

Instantiable (stateful) class which helps to build functionality of particular type i.e. **simplifies** work with given type.

**Support**

Sounds very similar to *Helper*, but if you consider `ConfigurationSupport` it feels like more than just helper, which makes things easier i.e. contains something that is **required/needed to get things work**.

Answer (score 1):

> From the accepted answer :

A Utility class can be understood to only have static methods and be stateless. You would not create an instance of such a class.

A Helper can be a utility class or it can be stateful or require an instance be created. I would avoid this if possible.

> Added how I understood about the support classes:

A Support class could be understood as the core components required to support a feature/functionality (like java.lang primitive classes and object classes) which provide the base framework can be categorized as support classes